# Force Figwheel to reload `defonce`

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

Figwheel has the great feature where it will reload all code, except for code defined in a `defonce` expression. This is great because you can persist application state as you code.

However, I'm in a situation where I want to change values in my `defonce` block. How do I force Figwheel to reload all of my code including the `defonce` expression?

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to `def`, save to reload the code, and undo it back to `defonce`.  That should do it!

If you want to reload a lot of code refreshing is better usually.